# Move two different objects to two different destinations so they arrive at the same time without using lerp

Tags: c#, movement

I might be missing some simple thing but I'm not I am able to wrap my head around this. Normally, if I want to move two objects to different positions so they arrive at the same time I would use a lerp like so:

```
var speed = 2.0f;
var amount = Math.Min(1f, this.elapsedTime * speed);

var obj1NewPosition = Vector2.Lerp(this.obj1Start, this.obj1End, amount);
var obj2NewPosition = Vector2.Lerp(this.obj2Start, this.obj2End, amount);

this.obj1Position = obj1NewPosition;
this.obj2Position = obj2NewPosition;
this.elapsedTime += dt;
```

But I want to do this in a way where I only add to their positions:

```
var speed = 2.0f;

this.obj1Position += obj1Vector * speed * dt;
this.obj2Position += obj2Vector * speed * dt;

// obj1Vector is a normalized vector headed to obj1End
// obj2Vector is a normalized vector headed to obj2End
```

How do I make the second approach work such that each object will arrive at the destination I choose at the same time by only adding to their positions?

I don't have to consider acceleration or deceleration, simply: have two objects arrive at their respective destinations at the same time and then stop.

Comment: Is there any reason that you don't want to use lerp?

Comment: @Honeybunch Yes, I can't set the position because other code will change the position later in the update. So if I lerp to a position it will override behaviour done by other code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something like this?

```
//first get their distances between their destinations. E.g:
var d1 = 150.0f;
var d2 = 200.0f;
var speed1 = 2.0f;

/* Extra part */
//------------------------------------------------------------------
if(d1 == 0 && d2 != 0) d1 = d2;          // To avoid 'divide zero' error.
if(d1 == 0 && d2 == 0) ShutDownYourPC(); // ;) No need to explain
//------------------------------------------------------------------

var speed2 = speed1 * d2/d1;        // This is the important point

this.obj1Position += obj1Vector * speed1 * dt;
this.obj2Position += obj2Vector * speed2 * dt;
```

Comment: Gah. So simple, this worked for me.

Comment: Although easy to solve, I commend you and up vote it for the simplicity and cleanness of that answer.

Comment: Beware when d1 ends up zero, as you'll end up with infinite speed for your second object.

Comment: Yes, don't forget to check it. Even so I edit the code.

Comment: Simple yet effective. +1